# Convert .bat command for mapping shared drive to AppleScript

Tags: macos, applescript, automation, smb, file-sharing

To get access to FTP file shares on a windows web server.

I need to run this batch code. I'm on a MacBook so how do I make it so I can run this sort of code?

```
net use W: /delete
net use W: \\10.0.2.3\web /persistent:no badPassword /user:office
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find a way to use the commands I provided in the question. Also i could not connect directly using the Finder function.

Instead I used TunnelBlick (VPN) to connect to the server.

Answer (score 2):

You can connect to a server just with Finder. From Finder's Go menu, choose Connect to Server (⌘K). Enter the server address as `smb://10.0.2.3/web` then choose Connect. You'll be prompted for your username and password which can be saved in your Keychain.

If you want to use AppleScript, you can use the following:

```
tell app "Finder" to open location "smb://username:password@server/share"
```

Comment: Is it normal for this to take this long? I just says connecting to server and stays there for a while

Comment: I got it to connect using ftp://xxx.xxx.x.xx but it prompts me with the password but it doesnt want to connect. When i got told every password would work. ?

Comment: @Granny Try using an empty password.

Comment: @NieDozejkob I tried, did not work. Got no clue what to fill in so ill ask someone to give/make me a login.